# preselect a date in the materialize datepicker by using an input value without separators

Tags: input, datepicker, submit, materialize, default

hello materialize community,

unfortunately it is not possible for me to preselect a date without separators in the datepicker.
if i use separators it works, but this does not help me for my application.

does anyone have an idea how i can solve my problem?

**example:**

**works**:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eo7eD.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <input type="text" name="mydate" class="datepicker" value="09/09/2025">

<script>
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() 
 {
  var options = 
  {        
        setDefaultDate: true,
        autoClose : true,
        showClearBtn: true,
        format : 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    };
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
  var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems, options);

  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

jsfiddle: 
    http://jsfiddle.net/dz0wrjho/2/

**did not work**:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47jWs.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <input type="text" name="mydate" class="datepicker" value="09092025">

<script>
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() 
 {
  var options = 
  {
        setDefaultDate: true,
        autoClose : true,
        showClearBtn: true,
        format : 'ddmmyyyy'
    };
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
  var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems, options);

  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

jsfiddle: 
    http://jsfiddle.net/dz0wrjho/3/

many thanks in advance

---

**UPDATE**

the date in the input field must be passed in the format 'mmm dd, yyyyy'.
with the option "format" you can only define the output into the input field.

documentation:

*format String  'mmm dd, yyyy'  The date output format for the input field value.*

[documentation](https://materializecss.com/pickers.html)

Comment: Why can't you use separators?

Answer (score 0):

Better to set datepicker Date with method setDate:

```
instance.setDate(new Date(2025, 09, 09));
```

And Input value with defaultDate property.